# class "com.mysql.jdbc.LocalizedErrorMessages" does not match trust level of other classes in the same package

Tags: java, security, jdbc, applet, digital-signature

I have a signed applet that access a database in localhost with JDBC/Mysql driver.

Everything works fine but the user gets every time prompted by an annoying warning dialog, that says that the application contains both signed and unsigned code.

I went into the Java control panel, advanced tab and checked Enable tracing, Enable logging, and show applet life-cycle exceptions, and pressed 5 in the Java console to show all logs.

Then I found out the following error:

```
class "com.mysql.jdbc.LocalizedErrorMessages" does not match trust level of 
    other classes in the same package
```

In my Manifest file I can see that `LocalizedErrorMessages.properties` has been signed (there is no `LocalizedErrorMessages.class` nor in the manifest nor in the library)

```
Name: com/mysql/jdbc/LocalizedErrorMessages.properties
SHA1-Digest: R1EZP+ilj5TImxZLeilYeyh3VBc=
```

Answer (score 3):

This error has been known to occur when packages are signed twice (that is the major reason for it appearing).  The easiest way to fix it is to strip out all the signatures and sign the code fresh.

> ..warning dialog, that says that the application contains both signed and unsigned code.

See [Mixing Signed and Unsigned Code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html) for background & fixes.